# Cannot connect to Azure DB after heavy EF query

Tags: entity-framework, azure

I am developing an ASPNET MVC 4 website for Azure, using Entity Framework 5.0.
The database is already created for the customer, and is in really poor shape (missing FKs, Indexes etc).
After 3 weeks of successful development, I ran an performance-intense query; after I cannot connect to the database...

- EF connection throws "A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable."
- After successfully logging-in through Management Portal, selecting the database returns error:

The weird thing is that the application runs fine after being deployed to Azure; and the Management Portal was responding as expected from another computer...

Any ideas? (apart from the obvious hatred which burns the DB's inner tables)

PS. I tried SqlConnection.ClearAllPools() and restarting my machine; nothing. Plus, I did not have sufficient permissions to access the sys.firewall_rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any details on the behavior of the SQL Azure DOS prevention mechanism, but from what I recall it seems likely your computer was marked as a threat and it may take a few hours before you can connect from your machine again. If this is indeed what's happening, all you can do is wait or use another machine with a different public IP Address.